# Slow database drop on MariaDB 10.1.44

Tags: mariadb

I've got a test system which is creating and dropping databases. I'm getting pretty poor performance on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine with 26gb or RAM and many CPUs and SSD storage. It takes 15 seconds to drop a database that contains 350 mostly empty tables.

This is my config at the moment:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC
innodb_file_per_table = 0
innodb-flush-method=nosync
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=2
```

Once the database is dropped and recreated the 350 tables are created again, this takes some time too.

Would really appreciate some pointers to speed it up.

Thanks

Comment: Is your machine otherwise starved of disk I/O? Is write caching enabled on your disks? What file system are you using? Can you reproduce the slowness if you put /var/lib/mysql on tmpfs?

Comment: Create 350 small files in a directory.  rmdir the directory.  I suspect it will take most of 15 seconds.

Comment: I suspect it would be quicker if `innodb_file_per_table=1` when those tables where created in the database. If so maybe its the purging out of the main tablespace that's the issue.